# Video.js components

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to add a ModalDialog component on top of video.js player, and fill it with custom HTML, for example from a DOM node. I'm only able to set its content to raw text.

`let modal = player.addChild('ModalDialog')`

`modal.content('hello')`

`modal.fill()`

`modal.open()`

I couldn't find any intructions on doing this on the official videojs docs.

Answer (score 0):

Add dialog HTML seperately to retrieve it later:

```
<div id="feedback-dialog">
</div>
```

Then build the dialog with

```
let el = videojs.createEl('ModalDialog', {
    innerHTML: $('#feedback-dialog').html()
})

let modal = player.addChild('ModalDialog', {
    'el': el
})
```